# How do I clear the values in a subset of an R dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

My ultimate goal here is to set some data in a part of our dataframe to NA (we have some participants who failed QC at some timepoints). I want to filter both by rows and by columns. In the iris dataset, I can get a similar-style subset like:

```
virginica_widths <- iris %>% filter(Species == "virginica") %>% select(contains("Width"))
```

What I'm looking to do is go back and change those cells in the original iris dataset to be NaN. I was kind of hoping I could do:

```
iris[virginica_widths] <- NaN
```

... but no dice. I feel like I should be able to do this with some variant of `mutate()` but I don't know how to filter it to only affect some rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to `filter`.  Loop `across` the column names that `contains` "Width", and `replace` based on the logical condition

```
library(dplyr)
iris1 <- iris %>%
     mutate(across(contains("Width"), ~ replace(., Species == "virginica", NaN)))
```

---

In the OP's code, 'virginica_widths' is a `data.frame` with `select`ed columns and subset of rows.  It cannot be used as row/column indexing

---

Also, in `base R`, this is more direct

```
widths_colnm <- grep("Width", names(iris), value = TRUE)
i1 <- iris$Species == "virginica"
iris[i1, widths_colnm] <- NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done tidy-style with a combination of `mutate()` and `case_when()`:

```
iris %<>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Width = case_when(Species=='virginica' ~ NaN, 
                                 Species!='virginica' ~ Sepal.Width),
         Petal.Width = case_when(Species=='virginica' ~ NaN, 
                                 Species!='virginica' ~ Petal.Width))
```

Since you're asking about replacing values in the original data frame, I threw in the `%<>%` operator in order to reassign the pipe's output back to the original data frame. Some people don't like those, but I find them handy.